# No muestra fechas desde PHP en consulta a Oracle

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo una base de datos Oracle a la que consigo acceder mediante PHP y visualizar información de ella, mediante el SQL Developer tengo una sentencia que ejecute y me devuelve estos resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero ejecutando la misma sentencia en PHP:

```
$tsql= "select orden as ORD, fase as FAS, CodMaterial as COD, maquina_id as MAQ, DescMaterial as DES, dhsalida as FEC, scg_MaterialesLotes.lote, scg_MaterialesLotes.lotecli from scg_fases inner join scg_materiales on scg_fases.IdBoletin = scg_Materiales.IdBoletin inner join scg_MaterialesLotes on scg_Materiales.IdMatOf = scg_MaterialesLotes.IdMatOF";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);  

if ( $stmt )    
{ 
  ?>
  <html>
  <title>PRUEBA</title>
  <body>
  <table border = '1'>
  <tr>
  <th align=center>Orden</th>
  <th align=center>Fase</th>
  <th align=center>Puesto</th>
  <th align=center>Articulo</th>
  <th align=center>Descripcion</th>
  <th align=center>Fecha</th>
  <th align=center>Lote</th>
  <th align=center>LoteCli</th>
  </tr>
  <?php

  while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    $orden = $row["orden"];
    $fase = $row["fase"];
    $puesto = $row["maquina_id"];
    $art = $row["CodMaterial"];
    $desc = $row["DescMaterial"];
    $fecha = $row["dhsalida"];
    $lote = $row["scg_MaterialesLotes.lote"];
    $loteCli = $row["scg_MaterialesLotes.lotecli"];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $orden . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $fase . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $puesto . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $art . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $desc . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $fecha . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $lote . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $loteCli . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }

  ?>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
  <?php
}     
else     
{    
  echo "Submission unsuccessful.";
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));    
} 

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);    
sqlsrv_close( $conn);
```

Lo que me devuelve desde el navegador es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Porque no puedo visualizar la información igual?

Comment: pon la estructura de tus tablas

Comment: La estructura no es el problema, si copiando la sentencia en un sitio si que ejecuta y muestra y en el otro no, que puede ser?

Comment: La primera observación que podría hacerte es que utilices alias en la tabla del `from` y a los campos que llamas de esa tabla en el `select` con el mismo alias respectivamente, quizá halla algo que `php` este interpretando de otra forma, solo haz la prueba

Comment: He usado alias en cada uno de los campos y sigue el problema

Comment: Ok, disculpa la molestia, pero podrías modificar tu consulta con esos alias?